# How to resolve File not found while loading the .properties file using Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am getting 'FileNotFoundException' while reading the migration.properties using Spring.

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config/migration.properties" />`

File directory:
Migration -> src -> config

Stack trace:

```
`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/migration.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:142)
... 8 more`
```

Comment: So to summarize, you told it to look on your classpath in a particular directory for a file, but did not put that directory on your classpath?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

Your file might not be at the location that you think it is.
I'd suggest you open your folders and actually double-check the path to the file. I often on my mac simply click "copy path to file" to make it easier for myself.

The path that you are describing here:
Migration -> src -> config
Would be

```
 /migration/src/config/migration.properties
```

If the file name is migration.properties

Another problem could be that the /Migration/src/config folder needs to be to your classpath. (Turns out this was the issue).

Comment: Migration is the Project name and then I have src folder and under src folder I have config folder where the file is located.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you right-click on the file and simply do "copy-path-to-file". Seems like someone downvoted my answer too. Not sure why

Comment: I did the fully qualified name but it is not working

Comment: What was the full path? And what exception do you get when you put in the full path to it?

Comment: This is the full path: /Migration/src/config/migration.properties and same error but with the new file path.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Migration/src/config/migration.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Maybe the classpath can't be found. Have you tried adding /Migration/src/config folder to your classpath?

Comment: I added it in the class path and now it is working. I accepted your answer. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: No problems Mike! I appreciate you accepting my answer. Especially since someone downvoted me earlier. I was just trying to help :) I thought it could be that too! Glad it helped you out. Actually I'll edit my answer too. So in case someone has the same issue, they can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like migration.properties not in classpath. You can use **file:///** to give absolute path and load it.